Número de Índice na lista
tenho que adicionar um número antes do nome do veículo
static void Novo()

{ using (StreamWriter arquivoVeiculo = new StreamWriter("veiculo.txt", true)) {

    Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Novo Veículo \n");

    Console.Write("\n Nome do Veículo: ");

    arquivoVeiculo.Write(Console.ReadLine());
}
}


Tá é o que quer faz, mas qual é a pergunta,? Qual é o problema? O que está impedindo de realizar a tarefa? Qual o resultado esperado, qual o resultado obtido? Onde está o [mcve]?Apresenta mensagem de erro? O que já  tentou para contornar o problema? Veja [ask] e obtenha orientações sobre o funcionamento da plataforma na [help].

Não repita perguntas, siga as orientações fornecidas na pergunta original. Se precisar comentar faça na pergunta original.
